# Fragment with inherited ViewModels

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel

Our app controls external devices and we are extending it to support a new device which shares a lot of functionality/UI with an already existing device.

So the plan was:

1. extract shared UI blocks from existing device to reusable fragments (which should use shared viewModels)
2. Extract shared ViewModel functionality to a parent ViewModel
3. Create child ViewModels for device specific UI/functionality (which access the underlying device models)
4. Create device activities with a composition of shared fragments, device specific UI and attach them to their ViewModels

[image]

But requesting the viewModel in a fragment

```java
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(DeviceBaseViewModel.class);
```

will throw a runtime exception:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class DeviceBaseViewModel`

I think I can not pass the viewModel instance to the fragment via a bundle.

**So, whats the right way to follow DRY-principles and share functionality in this example?**

Comment: Did you discuss about custom views? Or maybe you can create your own library. I think it would be more suitable for your scenario.

Comment: You probably need a custom view model factory, so that each activity (A and B) will be associated with desired view model subclass. You cannot create instance of abstract base view model (I assume this is what error says)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a static method to the base viewModel which checks the activities class and returns the right child viewModel

```java
 public static DeviceBaseViewModel getDeviceViewModel(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        if (activity instanceof DeviceAActivity) {
            return new ViewModelProvider((ViewModelStoreOwner) activity).get(DeviceAViewModel.class);
        } else if (activity instanceof DeviceBActivity) {
            return new ViewModelProvider((ViewModelStoreOwner) activity).get(DeviceBViewModel.class);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("no matching activity");
        }
    }
```

The reusable fragments can now access the right viewModel with

```java
DeviceBaseViewModel viewModel = getDeviceViewModel(requireActivity());
```

It's not as "clean" as I wished, but it works and I do not see any other solution to reuse fragments with various underlying viewModels.
If someone has a better suggestion or sees any problems with this solution, feel free to comment.